# Where is 'Token 0.1' standard defined?

Tags: solidity, tokens

In an example on https://www.ethereum.org/token :

```
/* Public variables of the token */
string public standard = 'Token 0.1';
enter preformatted text here
```

Why 'Token 0.1'? Where is the standard definition? 
I found ERC #20: Token standard on https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20 , but there is no clear link with the term 'Token 0.1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This standard definition ('Token 0.1') has no bearings to any community defined versioning.

This is something that the writers of this specific token implementation used to track their own implementation of the standard.